# If the Tathagata exists after death, is there anyone to witness it?

Tags: theravada, rebirth, buddha, self

This is different from asking, "does the Tathagata exist after death? or not? or both? or neither?"

Comment: What do you mean? Why do you think no one will witness it? Question unclear.

Answer (score 0):

This question was not answered by the Buddha not because of "there is no one to witness it".

The reason is something else, according to the Commentary.

**The question was asked from a position that believes in a "Person".** The questioner thinks there is a person called Thatagata and ask what will happen to that person.

In Theravada there is no any real entity of Person or Self. There are only Phenomena.

If the Buddha answered as "tathagata does not exist after death", **then the questioner would understand it as** "the person (self of) tathagata does not exist after death".

If the Buddha answered as "there is no real entity called person", **then it is not an answer to the question.** The Omniscient Ones talk to the point and don't provide answers in whatsoever invalid way.

There is a lesson series by a renowned expert in Abhidhamma which clarifies many of such issues:  ([Fundamentals of Theravada Doctrine](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLdluojKrWhDe6PRlcaHvxqvqKA5kwo1Dz))

Comment: Thus I heard: the Buddha was asked, "I do not ask about the spoken or the unspoken word", and he did not answer, because the person asked about nothing, so there was no need whatsoever to reply. Theravada is limited in its' attempt at hierarchical proof here, in Sanskrit it means, "wisdom of the elders", which is a behavior, whereas what is Vajrayana, "diamond transcendetal vehicle" is just a cool concept. Behavior versus concept- what is theoretical always wins. Yet the theory of wisdom, especially among elders, is very valid. Buddha could only answer one way.

Comment: I am convinced that Theravada philosophy, as outlined by Blake's link, is identical in rhetorical and literal sense to computer science: there are sets of heaps of aggregates and discriminants and perceptions of a model but- and one must really jump to zen here- it all means nothing alltogether to someone who is attached in any way to its' process.